# dplyr version of grouping a dataframe then creating regression model on each group

Tags: r, for-loop, group-by, dplyr, idioms

Can anyone suggest a `dplyr` answer to the following question?
[Split data.frame by country, and create linear regression model on each subset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27236072/split-data-frame-by-country-and-create-linear-regression-model-on-each-subset)

For completeness, the question and answer from the link are included below.

#### Question

For reference, here's Josh's question:

I have a data.frame of data from the World Bank which looks something like this;

```
  country date BirthRate     US.   
4   Aruba 2011    10.584 25354.8
5   Aruba 2010    10.804 24289.1
6   Aruba 2009    11.060 24639.9
7   Aruba 2008    11.346 27549.3
8   Aruba 2007    11.653 25921.3
9   Aruba 2006    11.977 24015.4
```

All in all there 70 something sub sets of countries in this data frame that I would like to run a linear regression on.  If I use the following I get a nice lm for a single country;

```
andora = subset(high.sub, country == "Andorra")

andora.lm = lm(BirthRate~US., data = andora)

anova(andora.lm)
summary(andora.lm)
```

But when I try to use the same type of code in a for loop, I get an error which I'll print below the code;

```
high.sub = subset(highInc, date > 1999 & date < 2012)
high.sub <- na.omit(high.sub)
highnames <- unique(high.sub$country)

for (i in highnames) {
  linmod <- lm(BirthRate~US., data = high.sub, subset = (country == "[i]"))  
}

#Error message:
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  0 (non-NA) cases
```

If I can get this loop to run I would ideally like to append the coefficients and even better the r-squared values for each model to an empty data.frame. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

#### Answer

For reference, here's jlhoward's answer (incorporating BondedDust's comment) making use of the *apply functions found in this excellent question:
[R Grouping functions: sapply vs. lapply vs. apply. vs. tapply vs. by vs. aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega)

```
models <- sapply(unique(as.character(df$country)),
                 function(cntry)lm(BirthRate~US.,df,subset=(country==cntry)),
                 simplify=FALSE,USE.NAMES=TRUE)

# to summarize all the models
lapply(models,summary)
# to run anova on all the models
lapply(models,anova)

#This produces a named list of models, so you could extract the model for Aruba as:
models[["Aruba"]]
```

Comment: Check several examples in `?do` and [**posts on SO**](http://stackoverflow.com/search?page=3&tab=newest&q=[r]%20dplyr%20lm)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Returning a list from `dplyr` is not possible yet. If you just need the intercept and slope @jazzurro 's answer is the way, but if you need the whole model you need to do something like

```
library(dplyr)
models <- df %>% group_by(country) %>% do(mod = lm(BirthRate ~ US., data = .))
```

Then if you want to perform ANOVA on each fitted model, you can do it using `rowwise`

```
models %>% rowwise %>% do(anova(.$mod))
```

but again the result is coerced to a data frame and is not quite the same as doing `lapply(models$mod, anova)`.

For now (ie until the next version of `dplyr`) if you need to store the whole result in a list, you can just use `dlply` from `plyr`, like `plyr::dlply(df, "country", function(d) anova(lm(BirthRate ~ US., data = d)))`, or of course if you do not absolutely have to use `dplyr` you can go for @SvenHohenstein 's answer which looks like a better way of doing this anyway.

Comment: @konvas, thanks!  As an aside for posterity, if one wants to store summary data (t-values, r.squared, etc.), we can do that with a straightforward modification of the answer above: `models <- df %>% group_by(country) %>% do(mod = summary(lm(BirthRate ~ US., data = .)))`

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the `lmList` function of the `nlme` package:

```
library(nlme)
lmList(BirthRate ~ US. | country, df)
```

Here, `| country` is used to create a regression for each individual country.

Comment: This is great too. But, I somehow have the following error message. `Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 0 (non-NA) cases In addition: Warning message: In Ops.factor(US., country) : ‘|’ not meaningful for factors`. Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I see the outcome. lmList was new to me. +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to use `dplyr`. I created `Brazil` using your data. So you have identical results for the two countries. You see intercept and slope in the final data frame.

**DATA & CODE**

```
structure(list(country = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Aruba", "Brazil"), class = "factor"), 
date = c(2011L, 2010L, 2009L, 2008L, 2007L, 2006L, 2011L, 
2010L, 2009L, 2008L, 2007L, 2006L), BirthRate = c(10.584, 
10.804, 11.06, 11.346, 11.653, 11.977, 10.584, 10.804, 11.06, 
11.346, 11.653, 11.977), US. = c(25354.8, 24289.1, 24639.9, 
27549.3, 25921.3, 24015.4, 25354.8, 24289.1, 24639.9, 27549.3, 
25921.3, 24015.4)), .Names = c("country", "date", "BirthRate", 
"US."), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("4", "5", "6", "7", 
"8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"))

#   country date BirthRate     US.
#4    Aruba 2011    10.584 25354.8
#5    Aruba 2010    10.804 24289.1
#6    Aruba 2009    11.060 24639.9
#7    Aruba 2008    11.346 27549.3
#8    Aruba 2007    11.653 25921.3
#9    Aruba 2006    11.977 24015.4
#10  Brazil 2011    10.584 25354.8
#11  Brazil 2010    10.804 24289.1
#12  Brazil 2009    11.060 24639.9
#13  Brazil 2008    11.346 27549.3
#14  Brazil 2007    11.653 25921.3
#15  Brazil 2006    11.977 24015.4

group_by(mydf, country) %>%
    do({model = lm(BirthRate ~ US., data = .);
       data.frame(int = coef(model)[1], slope = coef(model)[2])})

#  country      int        slope
#1   Aruba 11.02503 8.393295e-06
#2  Brazil 11.02503 8.393295e-06
```